# shell_exec with "svnadmin verify" returns nothing

Tags: php, svn, verify, shell-exec

I want to give output of svnadmin verify command from shell_exec()

```
var_dump(shell_exec('/usr/bin/svnadmin verify /Users/osman/Desktop/SVN/name'));
```

But it returns 'null'. 
How can i access the response of svnadmin verify ?

Im working with PHP 5.3.2 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Answer (score 0):

This error may be caused by the `disable_functions` setting in `php.ini` 
(or `suhosin.executor.func.whitelist` is Suhosin is installed).

You can have a look here to override it : [Overriding global php.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781927/overriding-global-php-ini-file)

Answer (score -1):

We had a similar issue and were able to get results back using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Comment: same result :( returns null when call with passthru

Comment: Make sure you give it a return arg. The passthru function doesn't return anything. 

passthru ('blah blah', $return);
var_dump($return);