# Overriding global php.ini file

Tags: php

I don't have access to global php.ini file since I am running my application on shared hosting and now what happens is I need to put my php.ini file in every directory to use the settings. But I am wondering whether there is a way to override the global php.ini file in my root directory for every sub folders instead of putting the php.ini file inside of every and each folder which isn't a good practice for further times.

If you are asking which specific option I need to change is `auto_prepend_file`

Comment: Do you have options to override which cannot be addressed with `ini_set()`? That's true of `register_globals` and some others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes! Not all php.ini options can be set, but many can be changed through .htaccess files, or the `ini_set` function, etc. See [these](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) [pages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

Comment: I cannot use .htaccess for that since it is in CGI mode so I am not allowed to use php_value stuff.

Answer (score 5):

For CGI/FastCGI use [.user.ini files <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php). Works since PHP 5.3.

Some shared hosters allow as well to place php.ini files into the webroot directory or at some other place. Contact your hoster.

Comment: I just want to add that it wasn't immediately obvious to me that `.user.ini` is the default name of the file (configurable in php.ini as `user_ini.filename`), and not the __file extension__.  So the name of your file should be `.user.ini` if you use the default.