# folder php.ini override main php.ini

Tags: .htaccess, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overriding global php.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781927/overriding-global-php-ini-file)

I have looked but can't seem to find an answer.
I am loading a php.ini file from my web root and wanted to know if it only contains one line, does that override the main php.ini e.g.:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/folder_name/include_folder"
```

is the only line in the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would override the main php.ini, unless you loaded the two php.ini files at once.

Comment: Will the rest resort to default then?

Comment: @Jjames Yeah, it will set all parameters to default settings. Because the php.ini just overrides the system defaults, as there is a php.ini of sorts pre-compiled into the PHP language.